# Arquitectura Big Data aplicado al cómputo de p-value ajustado en batches

Tags: python, r

### Datos

Por simpleza planteo el siguiente esquema:

1. Tengo dos DataFrames, uno con genes, el otro con estimulos (es un simple ejemplo, no viene al caso de qué sean los DF), los datos son contínuos:

```
                Gen_1      Gen_2       Gen_3                                        
    Paciente_1  220.43     12.959      12.311
    Paciente_2  270.27     12.870      13.234
```

```
                Estimulo_1      Estimulo_2       Estimulo_3                                        
    Paciente_1  220.43          12.959           12.311
    Paciente_2  270.27          12.870           13.234
```

2. Debo sacar correlaciones *todos los genes contra todos los estimulos* (utilizando ya sea la correlación de Pearson, Kendall o Spearman, es indiferente) estableciendo como resultado final con la siguiente estructura:

```
    Gen            Estimulo      Correlacion       P-value       P-value Ajustado                                        
    Gen_1          Estimulo_1          12.959      0.00311       0.00014
    Gen_1          Estimulo_2          12.959      0.00311       0.00014
    Gen_1          Estimulo_3          12.959      0.00311       0.00014
    Gen_2          Estimulo_1          12.959      0.00311       0.00014
    Gen_2          Estimulo_2          12.959      0.00311       0.00014
    ...
```

### Problema

El resultado del Cross Join (todos contra todos) puede resultar en un DataFrame con billones de filas. Para darse una dimensión del espacio requerido, dejando de lado las columnas del gen y el estimulo y considerando un resultado chico de 300 millones de filas necesitaría 300000000 * (16 bits de la correlación en pto flotante + 64 bits de p-value + 64 bits de p-value ajustado) = 5 GB aprox.

Con el fin de optimizar el uso de memoria, realizo el cómputo en batches, **el problema está con los p-values ajustados** ya que utilizo el método de *Benjamini & Hochberg (1995)* con la función [p.adjust de R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/p.adjust) (usando un wrapper en Python) que **requiere el arreglo completo de p-values**, lo que hace que me quede sin memoria.

¿Hay alguna manera de computar, ya sea a partir de otra librería u otro método estadístico similar el p-value ajustado en batches?

Ya probé con la técnica [FastLSU](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/32/11/1716/1742780) para poder filtrar algunos p-values que no sean significativos, pero según entendí, a la hora de obtener para cada fila el p-value ajustado necesito conocer todos los p-values totales. Si pudiera obtener para cada fila el p-value ajustado mi problema se resolvería ya que podría bajar los resultados de los batches a disco y adiós a las complicaciones.

Si alguien pudiera arrojarme un poco de luz sobre el tema se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Chequea si esto te ayuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764325/memory-efficient-benjamini-hochberg-fdr-correction-using-numpy-h5py . Pero parece que no hay muy buena solución aparte de "añade más ram!"

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me viene excelente!